# How to filter an array that excludes from object's property array

Tags: javascript

```
let project = {
    title: "some title",
    participants: [{
        _id: "12345678",
        name: "John"
    }, {
        _id: "44332211",
        name: "Jackson"
    }, {
        _id: "55667788",
        name: "Steve"
    }]
}

let users = [{
    _id: "12345678",
    name: "John"
}, {
    _id: "44332211",
    name: "Jackson"
}, {
    _id: "09876543",
    name: "Aaron"
}, {
    _id: "55667788",
    name: "Steve"
}, {
    _id: "22334455",
    name: "Xavier"
}]
```

How do I list out all the users that are NOT part of the project participants? includes does not work because project is an object...

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) them

Comment: wow, three upvotes and no code? and no result.

Comment: @mplungjan I searched for related topic before I ask, and I tried their solution, does not work that's why I came here to ask for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [`array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will work:

```js
let project = {
    title: "some title",
    participants: [{
        _id: "12345678",
        name: "John"
    }, {
        _id: "44332211",
        name: "Jackson"
    }, {
        _id: "55667788",
        name: "Steve"
    }]
}

let users = [{
    _id: "12345678",
    name: "John"
}, {
    _id: "44332211",
    name: "Jackson"
}, {
    _id: "09876543",
    name: "Aaron"
}, {
    _id: "55667788",
    name: "Steve"
}, {
    _id: "22334455",
    name: "Xavier"
}]

let result = users.filter(user => !project.participants.some(p => p._id === user._id));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is the same solution I was going to post until you did it, upvoted it.

Comment: thanks, I tried this filter + some function before I posted this question, it does not work on my actual code, when I console log project.partcipants[0]._id and users[0]._id, both has the same value, but it still evaluate as "false", guess I have to apply toString method to make it work

Comment: If the ids don't have the same type. For example one being an integer and on being a string you could also use `==` instead of `===`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of `find` with `filter`:

```js
var users = [{ _id: "12345678", name: "John"}, { _id: "44332211", name: "Jackson"}, { _id: "09876543", name: "Aaron"}, { _id: "55667788", name: "Steve"}, { _id: "22334455", name: "Xavier"}];
var project = { title: "some title", participants: [{ _id: "12345678", name: "John" }, { _id: "44332211", name: "Jackson" }, { _id: "55667788", name: "Steve" }]};

var result = users.filter(k=>!project.participants.find(p=>p._id==k._id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let project = { title: "some title",
    participants: [{_id: "12345678", name: "John"},
    {_id: "44332211", name: "Jackson"},
    {_id: "55667788", name: "Steve"}]
}

let users = [{ _id: "12345678", name: "John"}, 
{ _id: "44332211", name: "Jackson"},
{ _id: "09876543", name: "Aaron"},
{ _id: "55667788", name: "Steve"},
{ _id: "22334455", name: "Xavier"}];

var participants = project.participants.map(function(p){ return p._id; })
var non_participants = users.filter(function(user){
  return participants.indexOf(user._id) == -1;
});
console.log(non_participants);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first extract the participant ids into a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for fast lookup. Then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the users and check if the id is not included in the set (using [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)).

```js
let project = {
  title: "some title",
  participants: [
    { _id: "12345678", name: "John"    },
    { _id: "44332211", name: "Jackson" },
    { _id: "55667788", name: "Steve"   },
  ]
};
let users = [
  { _id: "12345678", name: "John"    },
  { _id: "44332211", name: "Jackson" },
  { _id: "09876543", name: "Aaron"   },
  { _id: "55667788", name: "Steve"   },
  { _id: "22334455", name: "Xavier"  },
];

const participantIds = new Set(project.participants.map(participant => participant._id));
const usersWithoutProject = users.filter(user => !participantIds.has(user._id));

console.log(usersWithoutProject);
```